# CSS 3 column footer with logo displaying incorrectly

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm working on a website where I require a footer with 3 columns, along with a logo on the left of the footer.

I'm having difficulty displaying the footer correctly, with everything in line.

**Here's an example of how it should look, and how it is currently appearing:**
[image: Example of how it should look, and how it currently appears on the website]

**The HTML I am using is:**

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer-logo-container">
<img class="footer-logo" src="footer-logo.png" alt="Logo" />
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List1</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List2</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List3</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer-copyright">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <br /> &copy 2015 Company</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**and my CSS:**

```
.footer {
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #2B2C2E;
}

.footer-logo-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
}

.footer-logo {
    line-height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.footer-content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.footer-content > h2 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer-content > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.footer-content > ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**View on JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/g4srqjzz/

How do I go about displaying all the content neatly, in three columns, with a logo on the side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following changes will work for you. Use `display:inline-block` for div.

```css
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2b2c2e;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #cccccc;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-logo-container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.footer-content {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 30px 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 150px;
}
.footer-content > h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.footer-content > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.footer-content > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer-logo-container">
<img class="footer-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Logo" />
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List1</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List2</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
    <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="footer-content">
<h2>List3</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3</li>
</ul>
<div class="footer-copyright">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <br /> &copy 2015 Company</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Check your updated code [Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/g4srqjzz/10/)

Answer (score 0):

mention `float:left` in `.footer-logo-container` and adjust it with top margin also adjust the width per your requirement

```
.footer-logo-container {
    margin-top:85px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float:left;
}
```

here is updated **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u5074dj/2/)**

Comment: Thanks - this seemed to have worked for the most part, however, the first few `li` elements are displaying on the same line. Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6u5074dj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably better off group them with a wrapper in your HTML, except the copyright block(move it outside of the ".footer-content" div).

https://jsfiddle.net/g4srqjzz/14/

Hope this will solve your issue.

HTML

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="list-wrap"> <!-- Added a wrapper to group branding and lists -->
        <div class="footer-logo-container">
            <img class="footer-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <h2>List1</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
                <li>Item4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <h2>List2</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
                <li>Item4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-content">
            <h2>List3</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Item1</li>
                <li>Item2</li>
                <li>Item3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-copyright"> <!-- leave this block outside of branding and lists wrapper -->
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. <br /> &copy 2015 Company</p>
    </div>

</div> <!-- remember to close your tag -->
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: #2B2C2E;
    /* ADDED CODE */
    display: table; /* Need to declare "display table" as parent element to "display table-cell" */
    padding: 40px;
}

.footer-logo-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 25%;
}

.footer-logo {
    line-height: 200px;
    /* float: left; */ /* Not required */
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.footer-content {
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    /* float: left; */ /* Not required */
    padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
    /* ADDED CODE */
    display: table-cell; /* Need to declare "display table-cell" as child element to "display table" */
}

.footer-content > h2 {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer-content > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    /* ADDED CODE */
    padding: 0; /* remove default ul box padding */
}

.footer-content > ul > li {
    display: block;
    /* float: left; */ /* Not required */
}

.footer-copyright {
    width: 100%;
    /* ADDED CODE */
    display: table-footer-group;
    text-align: center;
}
```